# Swift - Distribute an input integer equally to an array of positive & negative numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, integer

How do I generate an equally distributed array of positive and negative numbers from an input integer?
For uneven integers, the array must contain 0 as the "middle".
For even integers, the array must NOT contain 0, but rather have 0.5 steps, e.g. -0.5 & 0.5.
The input integer cannot be negative or 0. These inputs can therefore be disregarded.

Example:

```
Input : Output
Int 1 = [0]
Int 2 = [-0.5, 0.5]
Int 3 = [-1, 0, 1]
Int 4 = [-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5]
Int 5 = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
Int 6 = [-2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5]
and so on...
```

Is there a smart way to do this or is it a cascade of for-loops and if/else statements?

Comment: Lookup `stride`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`stride(from:through:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride).

1. Note how the last element (`end`) in your desired output array is always `(input - 1) * 0.5`. (You could also do this for the first element, but just flip the sign)
2. For `stride`'s `from`, just flip the sign of `end`

```
let inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
inputs.forEach { input in
    let end = Double(input - 1) * 0.5 /// 1.
    let output = Array(stride(from: -end, through: end, by: 1)) /// 2.
    print("Input: \(input), Output: \(output)")
}
```

> Input: 1, Output: [-0.0]
> Input: 2, Output: [-0.5, 0.5]
> Input: 3, Output: [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
> Input: 4, Output: [-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5]
> Input: 5, Output: [-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
> Input: 6, Output: [-2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5]

Comment: This is missing the requirement of excluding `0` from the output of even inputs (a simple filter should do the job).

Comment: This is the smart way I was looking for. Thanks for pointing it out! Works as expected and can easily be adapted.

Comment: *Usually* floating point numbers should *not* be used as loop variables because of the possible rounding errors. It works here because 0.5 can be represented exactly as a binary floating point number. – Alternatively, `let output = stride(from: 1 - input, through: input - 1, by: 2).map { Double($0)/2 }` with an integer based loop.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, learned something new. Amazing one-liner as always.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern seems to be:

```
Array((1...1).map { Double($0) - (2 * 0.5) })

Array((1...2).map { Double($0) - (3 * 0.5) })

Array((1...3).map { Double($0) - (4 * 0.5) })
```

In general:

```
func f(_ n: Int) -> [Double] {
    (1...n).map { Double($0) - (Double(n + 1) / 2.0) }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution and works as expected. I'll accept aheze's solution simply because other people, who have a similar problem, might find his answer easier to adapt. Nevertheless, Chapeau!